# Specifying a property's initial value within its declaration

Tags: c#, properties

Is there a way to define a property and set its value in one statement?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
public bool isConnected = false { get; private set; }
```

Comment: No you can't, although `false` is the default value for a `bool` property.

Comment: @Lee i prefer to initialize all vars even they have default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to define a property ans set its value in one statement in c#.
you can either use a backing field for the property

```
private bool backingField = false;
public bool prop{get{return backingField;} set{backingField = value;}}
```

or

initialize the property inside the constuctor

```
class class1
{
 public bool prop{get; private set;}
 public class1()
 {prop = false;}
}
```

or
just use a field

```
public bool prop = false
```

Comment: For me best way is to initialize the property inside the constuctor. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

No.

However, you can use a backing field with an initializer:

```
public bool IsConnected
{
    get { return isConnected; }
    private set { isConnected = value; }
}
private bool isConnected = false; // which is, in fact, a bool's default value
```

If you for whatever reason do not want to use explicit backing fields, you can always initialize the property in the class'es constructor. On the other hand, in the example above it would be possible to avoid the private setter at all, and use the backing field in throughout the class.

---

*Note that it is common practice to use `UpperCamelCase` for public members.*